# Testing graphql subscriptions with k6

Tags: load-testing, k6

Is it possible to test graphql subscriptions using k6 framework?
I tried to do it, but did not have much success. Also tried to do it with k6 websockets, but did not help.
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

`Grapqhql Subscription` is based on `Websockets` so this is theoretically possible to implement using k6 WebSocket.

You can also refer to the documentation for subscriptions [here](https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws/blob/master/PROTOCOL.md).
You can also use the playground and Networks tab in developer tools to figure out the messages/requests that are sent to the server.

Here is how I was able to achieve it:

```js
import ws from "k6/ws";

export default function(){
const url = "ws://localhost:4000/graphql" // replace with your url
  const token = null; // replace with your auth token
  const operation = `
  subscription PostFeed {
    postCreated {
      author
      comment
    }
  }` // replace with your subscription
  const headers = {
    "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol": "graphql-ws",
  };

  if (token != null) Object.assign(headers,{ Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`});

  ws.connect(
    url,
    {
      headers,
    },
    (socket) => {
      socket.on("message", (msg) => {
        const message = JSON.parse(msg);
        if (message.type == "connection_ack")
          console.log("Connection Established with WebSocket");
        if (message.type == "data") console.log(`Message Received: ${message}`)
      });
      socket.on("open", () => {
        socket.send(
          JSON.stringify({
            type: "connection_init",
            payload: headers,
          })
        );
        socket.send(
          JSON.stringify({
            type: "start",
            payload: {
              query: operation,
            },
          })
        );
      });
    }
  );
}
```

Hope this helps!